# Generate HTML file at runtime and send as email attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, email-attachments

I have a project requirement that we need to attach an HTML formatted log sheet to an email that gets sent to a user. **I don't want the log sheet to be part of the body.** I'd rather not use HTMLTextWriter or StringBuilder because the log sheet is quite complex.

Is there another method that I'm not mentioning or a tool that would make this easier?

Note: I've worked with the MailDefinition class and created a template but I haven't found a way to make this an attachment if that's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using WebForms, I would recommend [rendering your log sheet in a Control as a string](http://jrummell.com/send-a-completed-form-email-without-a-stringbuilder), and then [attaching that to a MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx).

The rendering part would look a bit like this:

```
public static string GetRenderedHtml(this Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sbHtml))
    using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        control.RenderControl(textWriter);
    }
    return sbHtml.ToString();
}
```

If you have editable controls (`TextBox`, `DropDownList`, etc), you'll need to replace them with Labels or Literals before calling `GetRenderedHtml()`. See [this blog post](http://www.jrummell.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/send-a-completed-form-email-without-a-stringbuilder/) for a complete example.

Here's the [MSDN example for attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx):

```
// Specify the file to be attached and sent.
// This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the
// current working directory.
string file = "data.xls";
// Create a message and set up the recipients.
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
   "jane@contoso.com",
   "ben@contoso.com",
   "Quarterly data report.",
   "See the attached spreadsheet.");

// Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
// Add time stamp information for the file.
ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
// Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  Razor for email templates. [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) or [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) might do the job for you

[Use Razor views as email templates inside a Web Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031474/use-razor-views-as-email-templates-inside-a-web-forms-app)

[Razor views as email templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368815/razor-views-as-email-templates)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145629/Announcing-MvcMailer-Send-Emails-Using-ASP-NET-MVC

http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc

Comment: I'm not currently using MVC so I don't believe this is an option.

Comment: Ok that's good to know but unfortunately I'm still running asp.net 3.5 and it appears that RazorEngine requires 4.0